# Ring epimorphism from principal ideal domain to integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, principal-ideal-domains

I'm looking to prove the following statement:

> Let R be a Principal Ideal Domain and S an Integral Domain. Then if there is an epimorphism $\varphi:R \to S$ with a non trivial kernel, then S must be a field.

I'm not really sure where to start with this one, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $S$ is an integral domain, the kernel of $\phi$ must be a prime ideal. Moreover, every non-zero prime ideal in a PID is maximal, so if $\ker(\phi)$ is non-zero then it is a maximal ideal, and then it follows from the first isomorphism theorem that $S$ is a field.

Comment: Could I ask exactly why the first isomorphism theorem implies that?

Comment: $S\simeq R/\ker(\phi)$ since $\phi$ is surjective, and $R/\ker(\phi)$ is a field because $\ker(\phi)$ is maximal.

Comment: Ah of course. I'm an idiot tonight, apparently. Thanks very much.

Comment: If you follow the category-theoretic conventions, a ring epimorphism need not be surjective (yeah, that's perverse), a ring homomorphism $h \colon A_1 \to A_2$ is an epimorphism in those conventions if for all ring homomorphisms $\alpha,\beta \colon A_2 \to A_3$ the implication $\alpha \circ h = \beta\circ h \implies \alpha = \beta$ holds. Do you happen to know whether for an integral domain $D$ and a field $F\subset D$ the inclusion $F\hookrightarrow D$ is an epimorphism in that sense if and only if $D = F$?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I wonder if anyone has asked that question here before.